# How to pop up / open bootstrap modal using javascript?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I need to show the bootstrap modal using JavaScript. I tried the code that I mentioned below got from internet, but It did not work. I also saw bootstrap.com website but did not find a good answer. I have used bootstrap 5.3.1. Here is my script:

```
<script>
$("#my_modal").modal('show');
</script>
```

I tried the code that I mentioned above. It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think bootstrap 5 already drop Jquery, so you have to use javascript to toggle modal.

Here's the example code using javascript

```
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('my_modal'), {
  keyboard: false
})
myModal.toggle()
```

You can try that code first and see if it works